# PowerShell - How do you get the latest windows updates from a list of servers? Array/For Each problem

Tags: powershell

I think the issue is in the $computer and foreach sections.  When I run this nothing returns. What am I missing please?

```
$computer = @('server1', 'server2')

ForEach ($COMPUTER in (Get-ADComputer -Filter ('Name -like "{0}"' -f $computer))) 
{if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
 
{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}

 
 
else {
  $key = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install" 
        $keytype = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine 
        $RemoteBase = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($keytype,$Server) 
        $regKey = $RemoteBase.OpenSubKey($key) 
        $KeyValue = $regkey.GetValue("LastSuccessTime"”) 
     
        $System = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")  
             
        if    ($KeyValue -lt $System) 
        { 
            Write-Host " " 
            Write-Host $computer "Last time updates were installed was: " $KeyValue 
        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work. But at the moment i have no possibility to test it.

Some explanations:
name var ADComputer instead of COMPUTER

$COMPUTER and $coMpUTeR and $COMputer and $computer are all the same because of powershell's case-insensitivity

create var outside the loop, if you don't change them in it

if    ($KeyValue -lt $System) makes no sense it will always be true, because the last successfull installation will always be in the past

Keep it simple, you can easily get the remote's registry value with the [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1), which allows you to "invoke" a script block on a remote host and returns its output. Also it is simpler to call the registry with the [Get-ItemPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet.

```
# create array computer
$computer = @('server1', 'server2')

# store Registry key
$key = “HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install” 

# iterate through computers
$computer.Foreach({
    # Get Computer from AD
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $_ 

    # Test if server is not reachable and report it
    if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $ADComputer.DNSHostName -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){
        Write-Host ("cannot reach {0} " -f $_) -ForegroundColor Red
    }else{
        # Get remote computers registry entry
        $KeyValue = Invoke-Command { (Get-ItemProperty -Path $args[0] -Name "LastSuccessTime") } -ComputerName $ADComputer.DNSHostName -ArgumentList $key

        Write-Host " " 
        # write LastSuccessTime to host
        Write-Host ("{0}: Last time updates were installed was: {1}" -f $ADComputer.Name, $KeyValue)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!  When I try this I get the following error.

Invoke-Command : Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:17 char:108
+ ...  -Path $key -Name "LastSuccessTime") } -ComputerName $ADComputer.Name
+ ~~~   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: Hey @JM1 I used the wrong property it has to be $ADComputer.DNSHostName instead of $ADComputer.Name -- I correted it in the solution

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  This is what I get with the new code.

Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again. At line:17 char:108 + ... $key -Name "LastSuccessTime") } -ComputerName $ADComputer.DNSHostName +  ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: Ok now I had some time to check it in an AD environment. This script now worked for me.